# How to remove the brackets in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I am using the this code

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Forward Enabled" 
    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"All calls to %@ are now forwarded to voicemail.\n Condition:\n %@ ",selected_phone_numbe ,selectedOption] 
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

[image: I want remove the brackets in alert view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selected_phone_numbe` and `selectedOption` looks either an *array* or *the string itself contains ( and )*.

Check for the class type (class introspection) if it is array, use array[0].

If it is string then you can replace `(` & `)` by empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Before showing the alert you can place this code ,you can replace all unwanted characters at once .

```
 NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];// declare set of unwanted charecters here.

selected_phone_numbe = [[selected_phone_numbe componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

selectedOption = [[selectedOption componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Forward Enabled"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"All calls to %@ are now forwarded to voicemail.\n Condition:\n %@ ",[[selected_phone_numbe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] ,[[selectedOption stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `selected_phone_numbe & selectedOption`  comes with that bracket remove it and then use that in the alert

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one. i hope it may help you.

```
NSString *msgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"All calls to %@ are now forwarded to voicemail.\n Condition:\n %@ ",selected_phone_numbe ,selectedOption]

     msgStr =  [msgStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
     msgStr = [msgStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Forward Enabled" 
    message:msgStr  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSString * changeString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"All calls to %@ are now forwarded to voicemail.\n Condition:\n %@ ",[[selected_phone_numbe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] ,[[selectedOption stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]];
    UIAlertView *callAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Forward Enabled"
                                                        message:changeString
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [callAlert show];
```

and Check this method :

```
-(NSString *)replacingString:(NSString*)mainString removeString:(NSString *)rmString withReplace:(NSString*)rpString{
    mainString = [mainString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:rmString withString:rpString];

    return mainString;

}
```

You got your answer;

Thanks :)